# Можно ли подключить DLL в python?

Tags: python, dll

Если можно то желательно пример

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно:

```
from ctypes import CDLL

lib = CDLL('some.dll')
lib.someFunction()
```

Почитать про ctypes можно в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).